# Avoiding a 100ms http request to slow down the REST API where it's called from

Tags: android, python, web, google-cloud-messaging, bottle

I'm developing a multiplayer Android game with push notifications by using Google GCM.
My web server has a REST API. Most of the requests sent to this API send a request to Google GCM server to send a notification to the opponent.

The thing is on average, a call to my API is ~140 ms long, and ~100 ms is due to the http request sent to Google server.

What can I do to speed up this? I was thinking (I have full control of my server, my stack is Bottle/gunicorn/nginx) of creating an independent process with a database that will try to send a queue of GCM requests, but maybe there's a much simpler way to do that directly in bottle or in pure python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883214/efficient-handling-of-long-running-http-connections-in-an-nginx-gunicorn-django):

I'm using **Celery** to send my notifications through a task queue.
I can't believe how simple it is!

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your clients are waiting for your server to send the GCM push notifications. There is no logic to this behavior.

You need to change your server-side code to process your API requests, close the connection to your client, and only then send the push notifications.

Comment: I know that's the problem, and I know I have to change this logic and send the push notifications elsewhere, I'm not just sure which way is the best.
I don't know a lot of python web framework, but in Bottle, to close the connection to the client, the routing method has to return the response. I don't think I can send the response in another way and to the notification sending after. I'm not too familiar with web server development. I will see if what you're suggesting is possible with Bottle!

Comment: Read about asynchronous calls in Bottle Python: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is making all networking asynchronous, if you don't do this yet.

The issue is that there will always be users with a slow internet connection and there isn't a generic approach to bring them fast internet :/.
Other than that, ideas are to

- send only few small packets  *or* one huge in favor of *many* small packets (that's faster)
- use UDP over TCP, UDP being connectionless and naturally faster